# Stl file exported in mm not cm

Tags: export

I have resized a model to centimeters and exported it as stl file. It is a file that I want to do 3d print.
However, when I open the file in Cura is shows that the file is in mm. I dont want to have to resize it  again in Cura

Comment: Have you applied the scale CTRL + A > Scale?

Comment: I've used Cura it seems that it always takes in mm. Not sure if it is an STL feature or something inside of the Cura software. So you have to scale your model in Blender in to be in mm and then import it again.

Comment: @rjg  What do you mean  CTRL+A. ?

Comment: @dimitarsp what would happen if I  scale the model to be in mm inside Blender. Keeping in mined that I want a real life 3d print of the model which in my case it should be in cm

Comment: @Ed1995 that is the shortcut to apply transformations in object mode.

Comment: Usually after I made the changes I saved the file again with the new parameters